# Expressão 'de resto' é errada?

Tags: gramática, expressões, literatura

Em um trecho do conto [Nova Califórnia (1910)](http://www.objetivo.br/arquivos/obras_literarias/Lima_Barreto/a_nova_california.pdf), de Lima Barreto, há:

> Ninguém escrevia em Tubiacanga que não levasse bordoada do Capitão Pelino, e
>   mesmo quando se falava em algum homem notável lá no Rio, ele não deixava de dizer: "Não há
>   dúvida! O homem tem talento, mas escreve: 'um outro', 'de resto'..." E contraía os lábios como se
>   tivesse engolido alguma cousa amarga.

Claramente, o gramático critica o uso das duas expressões. A primeira, 'um outro', é dedutível por haver repetição de pronomes; porém, por que a segunda, 'de resto', seria inapropriada? Com efeito que não se trata de uma locução culta, nem uma que se faça adequada em um cenário formal, mas em discurso casual, por que estaria gramaticalmente (seja ortográfica ou semanticamente) incorreta?

Comment: William, acrescentei alguma informação. O Capitão Pelino lia as obras de Cândido de Figueiredo, que era um dos que considerava *de resto* um francesismo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não há nada de errado na locução *de resto*, mas vários autores do século XIX consideraram-na um galicismo. Era provavelmente por isso que o Capitão Pelino não gostava dela. Um pouco mais à frente na história diz-se que ele lia Cândido de Figueiredo, precisamente um dos autores que condenou a locução como sendo “francês puro”.

Vejamos o que diz o dicionário Houaiss (desenvolvendo algumas abreviações, Lisboa, 2002):

> **¹resto** […] **de resto** aliás, quanto ao mais, quanto ao que ficou por dizer, além do mais […] GRAM a locução *de resto* foi considerada estrangeirismo por alguns autores

Um destes autores, o mais antigo que eu encontrei mencionado na literatura, foi [Francisco de São Luís (Wikipédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_de_S%C3%A3o_Lu%C3%ADs_Saraiva), escrevendo aqui em 1827 (grafia e pontuação originais):

> *RESTO* : Não reprovamos estes vocabulo, que he muito portuguez; mas o uso immoderado, que delle se faz, dá ás vezes ao discurso hum resabio de francezismo […] Quando se notão v. gr. os defeitos de alguma pessoa, e se conclue com esta clausula *du reste escellent homme*, seria má traducção dizermos, como hoje mui vulgarmente se diz: *de resto he hum excellente homem*. Em frase portugueza, diremos: *no mais he um homem excelente*, ou *aliàs he hum homem excelente*, ou *homem aliàs excelente*. &c. […]
>   [Francisco de São Luís Saraiva , *Glossario das palavras e frases da lingua franceza*, Lisboa, 1827, p. 117.](https://archive.org/stream/glossariodaspal00luizgoog#page/n127/mode/2up)

Outros críticos se lhe seguiram. Laudelino Freire em [*Galicismos* (1921, p. 66)](https://bibdig.biblioteca.unesp.br/bitstream/handle/10/26046/gallicismos.pdf?sequence=2&isAllowed=y) diz-nos que a locução *de resto* foi considerada “francês puro” pelos filólogos [Ruy Barbosa (1849-1923)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A2ndido_de_Figueiredo#Obras_publicadas) e [Cândido de Figueiredo (1846-1925)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A2ndido_de_Figueiredo#Obras_publicadas), e “espúria e bárbara” por [Silva Túlio (1818-84)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant%C3%B3nio_da_Silva_T%C3%BAlio); mas que [Heráclito Graça (1837-1914)](http://www.academia.org.br/academicos/heraclito-graca/biografia), admitido a proveniência imediata do francês, a considerava justificável pelo latim *de reliquo*, empregue pelos clássicos com o mesmo sentido.

Isto de julgar a correção de uma expressão com base na sua possível origem no francês ou no latim seria atualmente considerado discutível. O mais importante é que *de resto* faz sentido para nós, e foi por isso com certeza que a locução foi adotada pelos nosso melhores escritores, como Machado de Assis, Eça de Queiroz ou Alexandre Herculano. (Ver [Aurélio Buarque de Holanda Ferreira, *Linguagem e estilo de Machado de Assis, Eça de Queirós e Simões Lopes Neto*, Rio de Janeiro, 2007, p. 19 e 78.](http://www.academia.org.br/sites/default/files/publicacoes/arquivos/linguagem_e_estilo_de_machado-eca-simoes_-_internet-final.pdf))